# text.length is not defined in Javascript, but text is defined

Tags: javascript

I have a code that is supposed to show some text in a typewriter effect, but the console says that length is not defined. I do not know what to do, please help me.

```js
function typeWriter(theX) {
  var i = 0;
  text = theX;
  var leng = text.length;
  if (i < leng) {
    document.getElementById("theTexts").innerHTML += text.charAt(i);
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}
var speed = 50;
typeWriter('Frog-E Console');
var speed = 60;
typeWriter('Booting up');
```

Comment: When setTimeout calls your typeWriter function again, you're not passing theX (or anything) into your call

Comment: Side note: You're assigning to a variable that you haven't declared anywhere (see my article: [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html)).

Comment: Nick, what do you mean? I am confused

Comment: @NeonFoxer `setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);` eventually calls `typeWriter`, but with no arguments. This leads to `theX` being `undefined` when it eventually runs (hint: the 3rd argument and onwards of `setTimeout()` allows you to pass arguments into `typeWriter`)

Comment: When in doubt about why certain data is not available, open the dev console and add `debugger` somewhere in your code (e.g. the start of your function), then step through your functions. It will pause execution and tell you exactly what is available, and what decisions it is making based on the current data.

Comment: Ohhh! I understood, thank you Nick Parsons!

Answer (score 1):

By calling `setTimeout(typeWriter, speed)` you are calling `typeWriter` without passing it anything. This function expect one argument (a string), so you need to pass it :

```js
function typeWriter(theX) {
  var i = 0;
  text = theX;
  var leng = text.length;
  if (i < leng) {
    document.getElementById("theTexts").innerHTML += text.charAt(i);
    setTimeout(typeWriter.bind(this, text), speed);
  }
}
var speed = 50;
typeWriter('Frog-E Console');
var speed = 60;
typeWriter('Booting up');
```

```html
<div id="theTexts"></div>
```

However this doesn't produce the expected result, you should do something like this :

```js
function typeWriter(text) {
  const char = text[0]
  theTexts.innerHTML += char;
  if (text.length > 1) setTimeout(typeWriter.bind(this, text.substring(1)), speed);
}

var speed = 50;
typeWriter('Frog-E Console');
```

```html
<div id="theTexts"></div>
```

Comment: `this` is not used, so using `.bind()` is useless here, `setTimeout` passes its own n+2 arguments to the callback.

Answer (score 1):

Some issues:

- When `setTimeout` calls your `typeWriter` function, it won't pass it a value for `theX` so you end up with `theX` being `undefined`, so `text` is `undefined`, so you get the error.
- Your second `typeWriter` call won't wait until the previous one finishes before starting, so they'll stomp on each other. You can fix that by having `typeWriter` return a promise it fulfills when it's done.
- Your `text` variable is undeclared, making it what I call an [implicit global](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html); we don't need that variable, so let's just ditch it.
- Probably best to pass `speed` in rather than using a global.

Rather than having `setTimeout` call `typeWriter` directly, I'd probably use an inner function. See comments:

```js
// Accept both text and speed
function typeWriter(text, speed) {
    // Return a promise we'll fulfill when done
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        // Start out showing nothing
        let currentLength = 0;

        // Start the process by showing the first character
        tick();

        function tick() {
            // Add one to what we're showing
            ++currentLength;
            // Show it
            document.getElementById("theTexts").innerHTML = text.substring(0, currentLength);
            // Done?
            if (currentLength === text.length) {
                // Yes, fulfill the promise
                resolve();
            } else {
                // No, keep going after a delay
                setTimeout(tick, speed);
            }
        }
    });
}

// Do the first one, wait for it to finish, then do the next
typeWriter("Frog-E Console", 50)
.then(() => {
    return typeWriter("Booting up", 60);
});
```

```html
<div id="theTexts"></div>
```